# Is there good open source chess game for iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, chess

I am newbie with iphone development. I want to make a chess like game. Could you point me to some good open source chess like game with cocos2d.

Also i am interested in how to make multiplayer games (in this case 2 player chess based game). Is there any easy to use servers or i have to implement my own server side game logic and deploy it on my application server.

I read that open faint and game center have some features about multiplayer games but i am not quite sure how they work. Please point me to some tutorials/resources/open source games for that.

Comment: HI did ya get across a pgn file parser?

Comment: Checkout http://bigmultiplayerchess.com free and open source at https://github.com/lee101/mmochess

Answer (score 4):

Stockfish, mentioned in the other answers, released the [full source code](http://cl.ly/1O0v380R3P2a2A04060S) for their iOS app in their [support forum](http://support.stockfishchess.org/discussions/problems/321-how-to-integrate-stockfish-in-ios-app), which includes the game engine and UI.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely take a look at [Stockfish Chess](http://www.stockfishchess.com/). It's a chess engine, not a game itself. The repository is located @ [Github - StockFish](https://github.com/mcostalba/Stockfish). I haven't developed for Iphone, but it seems they have an app in the Apple Store. I've been playing around with it and it's pretty awesome.

Comment: The repo at github just includes the UCI engine source and there is no iPhone/iPad source code.

Answer (score 1):

[stock fish](http://www.stockfishchess.com/) best and probably only good open source chess app for iPhone. Shredder
Hiarcs are also good but not open source